# Facebook apprequests notification won't show in the Facebook iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm sending an app request from my application using Facebook SDK:

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"Check out this awesome app.",  @"message",
                               userId, @"to",
                               nil];

[self.facebook dialog:@"apprequests" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

This work great when the receiving user is on his Facebook page on the browser
The problem is that the user don't get the notification in the Facebook iPhone app.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Facebook App Dashboard settings, the Native iOS App section:

- Facebook Login: should be enabled
- Bundle ID: should match the one in your iOS app
- iPhone App Store ID: can be 0 if you don't have an iPhone app on iTunes
- iPad App Store ID: can be 0 if you don't have an iPad app on iTunes